# How to connect Gstreamer RTSP to iphone?

Tags: c, gstreamer, rtsp

Ok, So I installed gst-rtsp-server from the git repository in `/Users/justinjohnson/Documents/TrafficStop:`

`git clone https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server.git`

Next, I installed the appropriate dependencies *autoconf, automake, autopoint, and  libtool*.

This is where my understand breaks down. How exactly do I 'build' the pipeline? I'm very new to this so my apologies in advance.

Comment: [https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/ios/index.html?gi-language=c] follow this

Comment: I don't see where it teaches me to use gsteamer's rtsp server...